# Solution Verification of a problem on a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

**Question**: Solve the system of equations
$$ \left \{\begin{array}{c} 
\frac {4x^2}{1+4x^2} = y\\
\frac {4y^2}{1+4y^2} =z\\
\frac {4z^2}{1+4z^2} =x
\end{array} 
\right. $$

**Answer**: Let us take $0 \leq x \leq y \leq z$. If $x=0$ then, we get that $y=z=0$. If $x>0$ then $0<x \leq y \leq z$ and thus, we see that $$x^2 \leq y^2 \leq z^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{4x^2} \geq \frac{1}{4y^2} \geq \frac{1}{4z^2}>0 \Rightarrow \frac{4x^2}{1+4x^2}\leq \frac{4y^2}{4y^2+1}\leq \frac{4z^2}{4z^2+1}\Rightarrow y\leq z \leq x$$ and we conclude that $x=y=z$ and by substituting the result in the system of equations,we find $x=y=z=\frac{1}{2}$. I am trying to lay a justification that I can put the prefix $wlog$ at the beginning of the answer. Here it is. I am not sure whether it is correct or not.
**Justification**:(1) No matter what we take in the ordering (say $x,y,z$) then,we always get their cyclic successors(say $y,z,x$) in the second ordering as shown in the above case.

(2) In the original ordering,the first element is less than two elements but in the second ordering,it is greater than at least one of them
(3)Note that all elements in the first ordering will have a different position in the second ordering(Because none is the cyclic successor of itself)
(4)Thus, it must be equal to at least one of the two other elements. If we apply this same logic to the greatest or the last element we get that it must be equal to any one of the other two elements. Thus,we get an equality.(As we see that it will be of form $u_1=u_2$ and $u_3=u_4$ but we have only three elements $x,y,z$ and thus, at least one of them should repeat anywhere in the equality).
I am not sure about the justifications validity.Please help me here.

Comment: Your proof is correct.  You just have to observe that the system of equations is symmetric in $x,y,z$.  If $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, then so is any cyclic permutation of $x,y,z$.

Comment: [$x=y=z=0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%5Cfrac+%7B4x%5E2%7D%7B1%2B4x%5E2%7D+%3D+y%2C+%5Cfrac+%7B4y%5E2%7D%7B1%2B4y%5E2%7D+%3Dz%2C+%5Cfrac+%7B4z%5E2%7D%7B1%2B4z%5E2%7D+%3Dx+over+integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only cyclic symmetry in the problem, so it would be incorrect to assume any permutation.  However, WLOG you can still take say $z$ to be the maximum among $x, y, z$, and go through with your argument to reach a contradiction (essentially you would have two cases and argue that irrespective of the ascending ordering $x, y, z$ or $y, x, z$, you will have a contradiction).

A way to avoid the ordering cases is to appeal directly to AM-GM with the function $f(t) = \dfrac{4t^2}{1+4t^2}\leqslant \dfrac{4t^2}{2\sqrt{1\cdot 4t^2}}=t \implies f(t)\leqslant t$.  Thus $f(x)=y \implies y \leqslant x$, $\,f(y)=z \implies z\leqslant y$ and $f(z)=x \implies x\leqslant z$ so together we have the chain $x\leqslant z \leqslant y \leqslant x \implies x=y=z$.